# Query to find the difference between two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to build query to find the difference between 2 tables and then update the table(domain) if there is difference. Example :

Table 1:

| schema | table | domain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc_t | sample | sale |
| cde_t | test | supply |

Table 2:

| schema | table | domain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc_t | sample | finance |
| cde_t | test | manufacture |

First scenario is to find out the records where table 1.schema=table 2.schema and table 1.table=table 2.table and table 1.domain!=table 2.domain.In table 1 for second record domain is supply and in table 2 its manufacturing the code value of supply is also manufacturing hence these 2 records are same. I have the code values available for domain but not sure while matching these 2 tables how do I convert it and match it based on domain.

second scenario is for the first record in table 1 is having domain as sale and second is having domain as finance hence need to update the table 2 record with domain as sale as table 1 domain will take priority.

I have tried to create query for both scenarios but for conversion not sure how to compare like how to compare supply with manufacturing though they are same only as code value of supply is manufacture so there is no change required for second record :

scenario1:

```
Select t1.schema,t1.table,t1.domain
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 
   on t1.schema=t2.schema
  and t1.table=t2.table 
  and t1.domain!=t2.domain
```

scenario2:

```
update table2 t2 set domain=colasce(t1.domain,t2.domain)
 where t1.schema=t2.schema and 
       t1.table=t2.table
       and t1.domain!=t2.domain
```

Ouptut:

| schema | table | domain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc_t | sample | sale |
| cde_t | test | manufacture |

Comment: Don't forget to specify the expected result, i.e. complete the [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh-thanks,added it

Comment: I know this is off topic but i strongly suggest a tool to do this compare for you, something like https://www.devart.com/dbforge/postgresql/  - data compare tool (I have no ties with company). The cost of your time/errors/bugs to get the right SQL will be much more than the cost of the tool

Comment: @Sak please add more details on `the code value of supply is also manufacturing` ? To me it seems that both results are different

Comment: @ErgestBasha-It means that we have reference/alias available for different domains so for supply we have alias available as manufacture also hence the record should be treated as same.

Comment: @Sak *have reference/alias available* that is a key part on solving your problem. It is another table when you reference those alias or is it just a list, you need to post that as well

Comment: @ErgestBasha-Yes,there is a list...like for supply and manufacture its same.There are around 6-7 domains only.So if you can help me with generic conversion/compare for this example into sql ,I will use the same and write the next set by my own.

Comment: @ErgestBasha-can you please help with this.Or if you need any further information.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes,there is a list...like for supply and manufacture its same.There
> are around 6-7 domains only.So if you can help me with generic
> conversion/compare for this example into sql ,I will use the same and
> write the next set by my own.

You are missing a key part information which is the code value per each domain.

So if you add the code value per each domain it will be much easier.

Consider the following tables.

```
create table Table1  (
  "schema" text,
  "table" text,
  "domain" text,
    code_value integer
);

insert into Table1 values
('abc_t','sample','sale',1),
('cde_t','test','supply',3);

create table Table2  (
  "schema" text,
  "table" text,
  "domain" text,
      code_value integer
);

insert into Table2 values
('abc_t','sample','finance',2),
('cde_t','test','manufacture',3);
```

To change only the values with different code value domains use,

```
UPDATE Table2 
SET  "domain" = t1."domain"
FROM  Table1 t1
WHERE t1."schema" = Table2."schema" 
AND t1."table" = Table2."table"
AND Table2.code_value <> t1.code_value;
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/jfzehyG-)

---

Now if you do not have the  `code_value` column in both tables use , first add the column by using

```
alter table Table1 add column code_value integer;
```

Insert the code_value list

```
update  Table1 set code_value =  case when "domain" = 'sale' then 1
                                         when "domain" = 'supply' then 3 end
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/0-fLnKu3)